# Transparent screen doesn't allow scroll in Firefox but works in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have an iframe that I would like to block click events to, but allow scroll.

A transparent screen that looks like:

```
<div class="iframe-container">
  <div class="screen"></div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
}
```

In Chrome, I can still scroll the iframe through the screen but not click, but I can't scroll in firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: Is a JS solution ok? You could prevent clicking that way pretty easily, I'd think.

Comment: I'm using React. What would a React solution to this problem look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, it will work in all the browser

```
<div class="iframe-container">
  <div class="screen"></div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>

.screen {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: This works to allow scroll, but it also seems to allow clicks into the iframe

Comment: please use the following CSS code also i forgot to insert it "cursor: default;"

Comment: so finally you got the answer is it?

Comment: No, this still allows clicks into the iframe